# How can I store a RegistryKey object as a property?

Tags: c#, registry

While looking through the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_4) for the `RegistryKey` class I found the following message:

> This type implements the IDisposable interface. When you have finished using the type, you should dispose of it either directly or indirectly. To dispose of the type directly, call its Dispose method in a try/catch block. To dispose of it indirectly, use a language construct such as using (in C#) or Using (in Visual Basic). For more information, see the “Using an Object that Implements IDisposable” section in the IDisposable interface topic.

Does this mean I shouldn't/can't store a `RegistryKey` as a property in a class where there is no obvious time or place to dispose of it?

And if I can, when should I dispose of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store it in a property if you need the registry key for the life time of the object. Once you are done using the object you should dispose `RegistryKey` in the `Dispose` method. If your object is not disposable you need to implement `IDisposable` and call `Dispose` method of `RegistryKey` from there.

Example:

```
class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public RegistryKey Key { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Key?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah OK - and when would I call `Dispose` on the `Foo` object? Just whenever I am done with it?

Comment: Yes, "where you call dispose" depends on where you use an instance of Foo. For example if you are declaring and using it inside of a method you can simply use a using statement. `using(var foo = new Foo())` So it all depends on the scope of the instantiated object.

Comment: Great, thanks. What about `static` `RegistryKey` variables?

Comment: well the lifetime of statics is equal to the lifetime of the application, so you can't really know when exactly you are done with them and call dispose. you can dispose them at application exit.

Comment: @TobySmith you could arguably take the easy route with that because `static`s are per `AppDomain` and when secondary `AppDomain`s are shutdown via `Unload` everything is nuked.  Primary `AppDomain`s (your process has at least one) are unloaded at the same time the process exits and we know from that memory will be released and Windows will close all file handles